# List JSON values in a list?

Tags: jquery, json, each, getjson

I'm trying to list `v.name` in `<li>...</li>` using this working function (it's currently listing the last `name` value and putting it in a single `<li>`).

```
$.getJSON(projectMedias, function (data) {
    $.each(data.medias, function (i, v) {
        var name = v.name;
        $('ul').html('<li>' + name + '</li>');
    })
});
```

Any help to get it to cycle through, and list all `name` values?

Comment: use append() instead of html()

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** will replace previous content

Use **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead.

Convert this

```
$('ul').html('<li>' + name + '</li>');
```

to this

```
$('ul').append('<li>' + name + '</li>');
```